# Take screenshot and send it to printer Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, screenshot, printdocument

I am trying to implement the functionality of taking screenshot and sending the capture to printer. No need to implement the print functionality,user will decide whether to print or cancel that particular document. After digging around the internet and tweaking it to my requirement I am able to save the screenshot locally but **unable to send it to printer**.

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
        ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
        // capture entire screen, and save it to a file
        Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();


        // capture this window, and save it
        sc.CaptureScreenToFile("C:\\temp2.png", ImageFormat.Png);

        return View();
    }
public class ScreenCapture
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of the entire desktop
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Image CaptureScreen()
    {
        return CaptureWindow(User32.GetDesktopWindow());
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of a specific window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle">The handle to the window. (In windows forms, this is obtained by the Handle property)</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
    {
        // get te hDC of the target window
        IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
        // get the size
        User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
        User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
        int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
        int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
        // create a device context we can copy to
        IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
        // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
        // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
        IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);
        // select the bitmap object
        IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
        // bitblt over
        GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);
        // restore selection
        GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
        // clean up 
        GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
        User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);
        // get a .NET image object for it
        Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
        // free up the Bitmap object
        GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        return img;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Captures a screen shot of a specific window, and saves it to a file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle"></param>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    /// <param name="format"></param>
    public void CaptureWindowToFile(IntPtr handle, string filename, ImageFormat format)
    {
        Image img = CaptureWindow(handle);
        img.Save(filename, format);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Captures a screen shot of the entire desktop, and saves it to a file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    /// <param name="format"></param>
    public void CaptureScreenToFile(string filename, ImageFormat format)
    {
        Image img = CaptureScreen();
        img.Save(filename, format);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class containing Gdi32 API functions
    /// </summary>
    private class GDI32
    {

        public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020; // BitBlt dwRop parameter
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest,
            int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource,
            int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth,
            int nHeight);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class containing User32 API functions
    /// </summary>
    private class User32
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);
    }
}
```

Any leads/help will be appreciated. I have come across the PrintDocument class but they were mostly used in WindowsForm/WPF, was not very confident about using in MVC. Thanks in Advance

Comment: A webserver that takes a screenshot? Sounds strange to me.

Comment: are you trying  print from front end or backend? you can go two ways from here. one, if you want to use front end, you will have to send print command to browser. browser will handle it. on the other hand, you can use this example to start learning how printing works https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print?view=netframework-4.7.2 in c#

Comment: @J.vanLangen second that, but its part of requirement. I know better than to argue

Comment: does the printer support lpr?

Comment: @atoms Pardon me, I don't know what lpr stands for.

Comment: Its a, 'network protocol for submitting print jobs to a remote printer.' I've had success pushing documents over this protocol, can provide code if think it will help: Here it is: `command = "lpr -S 192.168.2.8 -P \"PRINTERNAME\" -o media=A4  document-format=text/utf8 \"" + sPathToFile + "\"";`